# OpenAI API returning empty response

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am trying to do a simple request to ChatGPT but get a 200 response with no content

```json
{
"answer": {}
}
```

Why can i not read the completion (also, how can i stream it?)

```js
import {
    ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum,
    Configuration,
    OpenAIApi,
} from "openai-edge";
import config from "../../config";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

const openAIConfig = new Configuration({ apiKey: config.openAIKey });
const openAI = new OpenAIApi(openAIConfig);

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<any>
) {
    let messages = [
      {
        role: ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum.System,
        content: "Hello, I'm a chatbot",
      },
      {
        role: ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum.User,
        content: "Hello, is Pluto really a planet?",
      },
    ];
    const completion = await openAI.createChatCompletion({
      model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      stream: false,
      messages,
    });

    res.status(200).send(completion);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the wrong convention for the POST.

i created the following file and everything worked

~/app/api/chat/route.ts

```js
import {
  ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum,
  ChatCompletionRequestMessage,
  Configuration,
  OpenAIApi,
} from "openai-edge";
import config from "../../../config";
import { OpenAIStream, StreamingTextResponse } from "ai";

const openAIConfig = new Configuration({ apiKey: config.openAIKey });
const openAI = new OpenAIApi(openAIConfig);

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { messages } = await request.json();

  let setupMessage: ChatCompletionRequestMessage[] = [
    {
      role: ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum.System,
      content: "You are a helpful chatbot, who thinks they are a dog that can talk.",
    },
    {
      role: ChatCompletionRequestMessageRoleEnum.User,
      content: "Hello, do you like playing in the park?",
    },
  ];
  
  const completion = await openAI.createChatCompletion({
    model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    stream: true,
    messages: setupMessage,
  });
  
  const stream = await OpenAIStream(completion);

  return new StreamingTextResponse(stream);
}
```